# How do I reload this module?

Tags: python, module, reload

```
from mypackage.pkg import mymodule
...
reload(mypackage.pkg.mymodule)
```

results in `NameError: global name 'mypackage' is not defined.`

How should mymodule be reloaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from mypackage.pkg import mymodule

reload(mymodule)
```

or

```
import mypackage.pkg.mymodule
...
reload(mypackage.pkg.mymodule)
```

Comment: I swear this wasn't working earlier on. Although obviously I'm talking out of my arse.